# Google_Auth_Exception: invalid_grant

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

So I've got a snippet of code that was working fine Friday, but is now throwing an exception:

```
// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
include_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

// Use the developers console and replace the values with your
// service account email, and relative location of your key file.
$service_account_email = 'thing@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$key_file_location = 'thing.p12';

// Create and configure a new client object.
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("HelloAnalytics");
$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

// Read the generated client_secrets.p12 key.
$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $service_account_email,
    array(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY),
    $key
);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}
```

where I've inserted `thing` for my actual values here. Namely, this exception is

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' 
with message 'Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_grant" }'' 
in repo/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php:364 
Stack trace: 
#0 repo/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php(315): Google_Auth_OAuth2->refreshTokenRequest(Array) 
#1 repo/test.php(25): Google_Auth_OAuth2->refreshTokenWithAssertion(Object(Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials)) 
#2 {main} thrown in repo/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php on line 364
```

I have found a number of people with this `invalid_grant` error, but none who just had it stop working one day. Any ideas on what could be causing this would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was working previously and you have made no other changes, check your system clock; this is the most common reason for the grant to fail. If the clock is ahead or too far behind, the grant will fail.

Comment: Forgot to mention I already looked into this, restarted and everything.

Comment: So my computer was apparently behind  `time.apple.com`? Changing my timezone and then changing it back fixed it. Thanks for pointing me in the rightish direction. Really frustrated restarting the mac didn't fix this.

Comment: Glad it worked! I've had similar problems before, even being just a minute or so off of an API host and not realizing it. The hoops we jump through in the name of security. :)